# Java Slot Machine Loop

Tags: java

I'm still pretty new to Java, so I'm having some issues working out this slot machine program. After you run the program the first time and calculate the rewards (say, you bet $20 and win $40, so your new sum's $120), it's supposed to loop back around and prompt "how much would you like to bet?" again, and then run through the game with your new sum (so you're betting part of your $120 instead of the $100 the game gives you at the start), and then continue doing that until you run out of money. But the way it's working now, the game keeps completely starting over, so the user loops around and starts with $100 every time. Any tips?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;
public class SlotMachineSimulation
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random randInt = new Random();

        System.out.print("Welcome to the Slot Machine Simulator!\n" + "\nActions:" + "\n1. Start a new game" + "\n2. View scores" + "\n3. Exit\n");
        System.out.print("\nPlease select an action: ");
        int userAction = user_input.nextInt();

        if (userAction == 1)
        {
            System.out.print("\nBefore the game begins, please enter your name: ");
            String userName = user_input.next();
            System.out.print("\nGame start! You will begin with $100.00." + "\nEnter a negative value to quit the game. " + "Good luck, " + userName + "!\n");

            double startingSum = 100.00;
            double userTotal = 0.0;
            System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f\n", startingSum);

            do 
            {
                System.out.print("\nHow much would you like to bet? ");
                double userBet1 = user_input.nextDouble();  
                userTotal = (startingSum - userBet1);

                //Beginning of random number generation 
                int val1 = randInt.nextInt(6) + 1;
                int val2 = randInt.nextInt(6) + 1;
                int val3 = randInt.nextInt(6) + 1;
                String valName1 = " ", valName2 = " ", valName3 = " ";  //For assignment of slot machine names to randomly generated values

                switch (val1)
                {
                    case 1:
                        valName1 = "Cherries";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        valName1 = "Oranges";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        valName1 = "Plums";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        valName1 = "Bells";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        valName1 = "Melons";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        valName1 = "Bars";
                        break;
                }

                switch (val2)
                {
                    case 1:
                        valName2 = "Cherries";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        valName2 = "Oranges";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        valName2 = "Plums";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        valName2 = "Bells";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        valName2 = "Melons";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        valName2 = "Bars";
                        break;
                }

                switch (val3)
                {
                    case 1:
                        valName3 = "Cherries";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        valName3 = "Oranges";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        valName3 = "Plums";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        valName3 = "Bells";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        valName3 = "Melons";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        valName3 = "Bars";
                        break;
                }

                System.out.println("\n-------------------------------");
                System.out.printf("%-12s%-10s%5s\n", valName1, valName2, valName3);
                System.out.print("-------------------------------\n");

                //Beginning of reward calculation
                if (val1 == val2 || val2 == val3 || val1 == val3)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nNumber of matches: 1");
                    double doubleReward = (userBet1 * 2);
                    double postBetSum = (userTotal + doubleReward);
                    System.out.printf("You have won: $%.2f", doubleReward);
                    System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", postBetSum);
                }
                else if (val1 == val2 && val2 == val3)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nNumber of matches: 3");
                    double tripleReward = (userBet1 * 3);
                    double postBetSum = (userTotal + tripleReward);
                    System.out.printf("\nYou have won: $%.2f",tripleReward);
                    System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", postBetSum);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("\nNumber of matches: 0");
                    System.out.println("You have won: $0.00");
                    System.out.printf("You currently have: $%.2f", userTotal);
                }
            } while (userTotal > 0.00);
        } //end of #1 option
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested out this code, and this problem does not occur for me. Is this exactly your code?

Comment: i see a possible error, i have 32 i play 31 and i lose, and he give me 69$...

Comment: `userTotal = (startingSum - userBet1);` should probably be `userTotal -= userBet1;`, and `userTotal` should probably be initialized to 100.

Comment: Your slot machine will never pay out triple. Any triple is also a double and you are checking for double first.

Comment: You might want to compare the strings with .equals() rather than ==.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line and should work

```
double userTotal = 100.0;
userTotal -= userBet1;
```

use even

```
String valName1 = genName(), valName2 = genName(), valName3 = genName();
```

and method

```
public static String genName()
{
    int ran = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
    switch (ran)
    {
        case 1:
            return "Cherries";
        case 2:
            return "Oranges";
        case 3:
            return "Plums";
        case 4:
            return "Bells";
        case 5:
            return "Melons";
        case 6:
            return "Bars";
            default:
                return "Cherries";
    }
}
```

to clear code =)

Comment: Your answer was terse enough to satisfy the main issue, but the extra bits are a bit...much.  Your answer's right, but there's a lot of extra noise here.

Comment: Are you kinning me? other even write the same code i wrote and the code of the question, and you say *there's a lot of extra noise here* ?

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting userbet from startingSum in every iteration and checking the condition with userTotatl. You need to assign as follows:

`userTotal = startingSum (Before the loop);`

and inside the loop

`userTotal-= userbet;`

Answer (score -1):

Problems in your code:

1. for every iteration of the loop the **userTotal** is **100.00-userBet1**.  By writing code this way you don't maintain **userTotal** value for the next iteration.
2. in your if-else-if ladder,if first condition match then control exit from the if-else-if construct and user will never get a triple reward.
3. in your if-else-if blocks you are not maintaing **userTotal**. you are just assign it to a local variable **postBetSum**.

Solutions:

1. Declare and initialize a **count=0** variable outside the loop. inside loop just increase the counter by 1. check if it is the first iteration i.e. **count==1** , then **userTotal=100.0-userBet1** . otherwise **userTotal=userTotal-userBet1**
2. make your second condition first in the if-else-if ladder. in this way you are sure if three or two(according to your code) match are there then you'll get the triple reward. if not then it will check for the next else-if block for a single match, if found then user will get double reward.
3. you can maintain **userTotal** by writing this way **userTotal+=doubleReward** . this statement make sure that **userTotal** is retaining its value after getting the reward.

All this, plus you can put your switch construct in a method which just returns a string instead of writing it three times.

Now Try this:

```
class SlotMachineSimulation
{
 public static String getValName(int val){
    String valName=" ";
    switch (val)
    {
        case 1:
            valName = "Cherries";
            break;
        case 2:
            valName = "Oranges";
            break;
        case 3:
            valName = "Plums";
            break;
        case 4:
            valName = "Bells";
            break;
        case 5:
            valName = "Melons";
            break;
        case 6:
            valName = "Bars";
            break;
    }
    return valName;

}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random randInt = new Random();

    System.out.print("Welcome to the Slot Machine Simulator!\n" + "\nActions:" + "\n1. Start a new game" + "\n2. View scores" + "\n3. Exit\n");
    System.out.print("\nPlease select an action: ");
    int userAction = user_input.nextInt();

    if (userAction == 1)
    {
        System.out.print("\nBefore the game begins, please enter your name: ");
        String userName = user_input.next();
        System.out.print("\nGame start! You will begin with $100.00." + "\nEnter a negative value to quit the game. " + "Good luck, " + userName + "!\n");


        double userTotal = 0.0;
        System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f\n", 100.00);
        int count=0;
        do 
        {
            System.out.print("\nHow much would you like to bet? ");
            double userBet1 = user_input.nextDouble();
            count++;
            if(count==1){
                userTotal=100.0-userBet1;
            }else{
                userTotal=userTotal-userBet1;
            }


            //Beginning of random number generation 
            int val1 = randInt.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int val2 = randInt.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int val3 = randInt.nextInt(6) + 1;

            String valName1,valName2,valName3;  //For assignment of slot machine names to randomly generated values

            valName1=getValName(val1);
            valName2=getValName(val2);
            valName3=getValName(val3);

            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------");
            System.out.printf("%-12s%-10s%5s\n", valName1, valName2, valName3);
            System.out.print("-------------------------------\n");

            //Beginning of reward calculation
            if (val1 == val2 && val2 == val3 && val3==val1)//check this condition first otherwise even after matching these values user never get more than double
            {
                System.out.println("\nNumber of matches: 1");
                double doubleReward = (userBet1 * 2);
                userTotal+=doubleReward;

                System.out.printf("You have won: $%.2f", doubleReward);
                System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", userTotal);
            }
            else if (val1 == val2 || val2 == val3 || val1 == val3)
            {
                System.out.println("\nNumber of matches: 3");
                double tripleReward = (userBet1 * 3);
                userTotal+=tripleReward;

                System.out.printf("\nYou have won: $%.2f",tripleReward);
                System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", userTotal);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("\nNumber of matches: 0");
                System.out.println("You have won: $0.00");
                System.out.printf("You currently have: $%.2f", userTotal);
            }
        } while (userTotal > 0.00);
    } //end of #1 option
    user_input.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: It's all code and no explanation.  I'd rather see explanation as to *why* your code works.

Answer (score -2):

Simple, at the start of your loop you are assigning your total as:

```
userTotal = (startingSum - userBet1);
```

This translates to

```
userTotal = ($100 - userBet1);
```

So obviously the user is reset to $100 after each round.

Try this instead:

```
double userTotal = startingSum;
...
userTotal -= userBet1;
```

There are also several other issues with this code (such as three identical case statement bodies, which should be condensed into one with a loop), and honestly it may be worthwhile to consider posting your program on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as the feedback you can obtain there would offer you more in the ways of learning Java and preventing mistakes such as the one in this program.

Comment: Your answer is fine - except the part where you mention Code Review.  Remove that part.  Please.

Comment: According to what's "on topic" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner *unlikely to help future readers.*" (emphasis mine). For professional & enthusiast programmers (stackoverflow's audience), the mistake in this question is extremely obvious, and so in my opinion, the question really provides no value to the community. I would argue it would be of value on codereview.stackexchange.com, so I will not remove that part of my answer.

Comment: Since this question is about "trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets", it would most certainly **not** be of value on Code Review.

Comment: Hardly a snippet of code -- it's an entire program. Anyway, I should clarify that independent of the asker's debugging issue, he should consider bringing his code to codereview, since there were several issues in that code which could be addressed there.